# What kind of IT security applications do you guys run on your laptop/desktop?

Tags: tools, firewalls, network-scanners, defense

I know a lot of people run different security applications on their laptops/desktops. I use Little Snitch on my Macbook Pro. I like to know where my applications are sending data and where I am receiving data from.

What are some of your security applications that you guys run on real-time **to protect your computer**?

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  Your question text seems to be generically asking about "security applications" but you've tagged the question specifically with "firewalls" and "network-scanners".  Are you uninterested in antivirus/anti-malware tools, sandboxes, or any of the other useful types of real-time protection utilities?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent?  Data on a lost laptop?  Don't want to become a spambot zombie?

Answer (score 4):

You mean in the background as a service?

- Nothing. Bogs down the system for no useful result.

Comment: Yes, I mean in the background as a service. Pretty much how Little Snitch works.

Comment: Kernels are for Sucka's,  An't nothing background about my system.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I run, on my personal laptop, these active security tools:

- [eljefe](http://www.immunityinc.com/products-eljefe.shtml) (client) - Basically a client that reports processes information to the eljefe server (truthfully the tool is very cludgy and i'm only running it because i'm testin it out)
- [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/default.aspx)
- Windows 7 Firewall
- [PeerGuardian](http://phoenixlabs.org/pg2/)
- [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/)
- Also, all logging/auditing is enabled for windows and the firewall

Currently I run, on my personal desktop, these active security tools:

- [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/default.aspx)
- Windows 7 Firewall
- [PeerGuardian](http://phoenixlabs.org/pg2/)
- [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/)
- Also, all logging/auditing is enabled for windows and the firewall

Additionally, i'll use the built in tools as well as [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), [keepass](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://keepass.info/&rct=j&q=keepass&ei=X9etTbDYN8jogQfxrc31Cw&usg=AFQjCNFjJ7S8ZplrJAHDP8XPoAjZuv6-EA&cad=rja), [glary's utilities](http://www.glaryutilities.com/), and some other odds and ends of clean-up tools (For some reason I'm obsessed with cleaning the white-space of my laptop and desktop).  As for anti-malware I use [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (along with [Windows Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/default.aspx) as i listed above).

Alright, these are for common use...... if i'm doing sec auditing/vuln assessment I'll boot into either an XP partition with some tools which has practically no defenses or a live CD/USB (ie [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/)).

Is this really the type of response you were looking for, or is there something else you're going after?

If you'd like some more specific ideas, please post them.  It seems like you're an apple user, and that's a whole different beast to tame.

Answer (score 2):

- Microsoft Security Essentials
- KeePass
- TrueCrypt

Answer (score 1):

**FIREFOX**

With these addons:

```
FireBug
Tamperdata
useragent-switer
noscript (Love the anti-xss and anti-csrf features)
FireSheep (Too easy)
AdBlock Plus
https-everywhere (EFF)
Tor-Button (EFF)
```

Comment: BTW, FireSheep will not work on atheros wireless chipsets, which made me quite mad when i realized that the "cool" session hijacking tool that i heard about in class didn't work on my laptop... which happens to be beautiful for every other wireless tool I've tried. Not too much of a loss.

Comment: How's FireSheep a security (defense) application?  I would think BlackSheep would make the list instead?  Then again, it seems the OP didn't specify (another thing) whether he wanted defensive/offensive or black-hat/white-hat tools.  (Though, technically requests for black-hat tools are off-topic here.)

Comment: @Iszi yeah few on there are for defense,  like adblock.  But the majority are pen-testing tools.

Comment: All of these plugins are amazing.

Comment: Certificate Patrol is useful also, for identifying if the traffic you thought was secure is actually being proxied.

Comment: What does (EFF) means?

Comment: @Pacerier : Electronic Frontier Foundation

Comment: @talonx I dun get it..

Comment: @Pacerier : See https://www.eff.org/about . The extensions above were created by EFF.